# Pullback of an Immersion $j: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I'm preparing for some exams and this problem is from an older exam:

"On $\mathbb{R}^4$, with standard coordinates $(x, y, z, t)$, consider the 1-form $\theta = x \, dy − y \, dx + z \, dt − t \, dz$. Is there a smooth immersion $j : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ such that $j^∗ \theta = 0$ everywhere?"

I'm not sure of where to start besides of course supposing there is such an immersion and seeing if it leads to a contradiction. I've also differentiated the 1-form just to see if any patterns come of it but there are none as far as I can tell. However, the 1-form does look very symmetric and I'm sure it was chosen with care.

I was told to look at some integrability conditions such as the kernel of some map and apply Frobenius' Theorem. However, I only know of the version of Frobenius' theorem in the context of taking the Lie bracket of vector fields. Any help or hints are helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative#In_terms_of_invariant_formula) that for any smooth fields $X$ and $Y$, one has:
$$\mathrm{d}\theta(X,Y)=X(\theta(Y))-Y(\theta(X))-\theta([X,Y]).$$
Let $\xi:=\ker(\theta)$, then according to [Frobenius' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(differential_topology)) $\xi$ is integrable if, and only, if $\theta\wedge\mathrm{d}\theta=0$.

In this case, one has $\theta\wedge\mathrm{d}\theta\neq 0$, so that there is no immersed hypersurface of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with tangent bundle $\xi$. Therefore, such an immersion cannot exist, since $j^*\theta=0$ exactly means that $Tj(\mathbb{R}^3)\subset\xi$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you explain the definition of the kernel of $\theta$? Is it all the vector fields which are mapped to 0?

Comment: For sure, one has: $$\ker(\theta)=\coprod_{x\in\mathbb{R}^4}\ker(\theta_x)=\coprod_{x\in\mathbb{R}^4}\left\{v\in T_x\mathbb{R}^4\textrm{ s.t. }\theta_x(v)\right\}.$$ This is a field of tangent hyperplanes formed by the usual kernel of the linear form obtained by evaluating $\theta$ at a point of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: Thank you; and what do you mean by $T j(\mathbb{R}^3)$?

Comment: This is the tangent bundle of the immersed manifold given by the image of $j$.

Comment: Oh, that's silly of me. Of course that's what you mean. Thank you very much!

Comment: There's no silly question, glad to have helped!

Comment: Sorry to raise this again; I thought I saw understood why there is no immersion: for $\xi = \ker \theta$ to be integrable, we need every point in $\mathbb{R}^4$ to be in an integral submanifold of $\xi$. But an immersion, $j$ only gives one integral submanifold. Why should a single immersion contradict anything? Can't $\xi$ be sort of locally integrable at some points in $j(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and not other points?

Comment: Integrability is a **local** condition, not a global one!

Comment: Hmm, so if $\xi$ is not integrable, then there are some points not in integral submanifolds. When we look at $\theta \wedge d \theta$, we see it is not equal to 0 everywhere except the origin. So the origin is the only potential point contained in an integral submanifold. But then, you need $\theta \wedge d \theta = 0$ on a small neighborhood of the origin at least to have an integral submanifold, which we don't have.